# "load_texture" feature not existing in Ursina Engine

Tags: python

I recently started to use Ursina Engine (Python) but when i try to load a texture via 'load_texture()' command, it doesn't work. Here's what it says.

`ursina version: 3.5.0 package_folder: C:\Users\minec\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\ursina asset_folder: D:\Voxel blender_paths: {'default': WindowsPath('D:/Blender/blender.exe')} screen resolution: (1920, 1080) Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:\Voxel\voxel.py", line 4, in <module> texture = load_texture('assets/texture/cobblestone.png') File "C:\Users\minec\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\ursina\texture_importer.py", line 40, in load_texture t =  Texture(filename.resolve()) File "C:\Users\minec\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 23, in __init__ self._texture = loader.loadTexture(Filename.fromOsSpecific(str(value))) NameError: name 'loader' is not defined`

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same problem, don't know still how to fix it but managed to find a way around it.
Instead of going for example:

```
x = load_texture('x.png')
[...]
texture = x
```

I did right away:

```
texture = ('x.png')
```

**EDIT**

Run the

```
app=Ursina()
```

prior to importing/loading the textures

Answer (score 0):

### Solution and Explanation

If you want to use the texture importer, you need to import another part of `Ursina`...

```
from ursina.texture_importer import load_texture
```

This allows you to use the texture importer.

---

### Using Custom Textures the Easy Way

If you want to use a custom texture map, you don't need to texture import, but simply do...

```
from ursina import *
app = Ursina()

model = Entity(model='cube', texture='my_image.png')

app.run()
```

*(where, of course, `my_image.png` is your texture, you can change the `my image` part to any name of an image)*

Comment: You should not put the `.png` at the end of a texture. In general, you should never put the file extension for a file in Ursina, except for `.gif`.

Comment: I have never been sure why, but why do they require you have `.gif`?

Comment: And how to you specify the path to this image? How does it know which folder contains it?

Comment: If your image is in the folder `assets`, your string to input as the texture parameter is `assets/my_image.png`. Just use path to the image.